# https and wordpress breaks posts

Tags: posts, apache, ssl, https, linux

I have a wordpress http site which still works just fine. I added https and the first page works but none of the post pages do.

server: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS (lucid) running Apache 2.2.14 SSL through RapidSSL

** EDIT **

Here's the 404 I see instead of a post (make note, on the exact url but with `https` I'm able to see my content)

---

**Not Found**

The requested URL /shortcuts/ was not found on this server.

*Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at www.mydomain.com Port 443*

---

Comment: What exactly do you see on the other post pages?

Comment: I made an edit to the original question and added the apache 404 error page I see instead of the content.

Comment: At first glance this seems like a permalink problem.

Comment: Do you use Shared SSL?

Comment: if by shared SSL you mean multiple virtual hosts using SSL then yes. differing domains though, with different certs. I saw this all as a potential htaccess issue, but yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best educated guess is to perform a checklist on the following:

- Take a look at the virtual host configuration files for your domains, if you have access to them. Ensure that they agree with the corresponding WordPress installations on your machine(s).
- If your Virtual Host configurations are written correctly and as intended, then the next step is to check if your websites work with "Pretty Links" disabled. If they do, then we know for a fact that WordPress is probably configured incorrectly for using SSL, and that the URL Rewriting settings need to be changed for WordPress. The easiest way to do that is through the use of this plugin:

  - [WordPress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/)

Potential Resources:

- [Apache 2.2 Manual - Virtual Host Example Configurations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)
- [Administration Over SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL)
- [Blog Tutorial - How to Secure WordPress with SSL using a Plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-secure-your-wordpress-pages-with-ssl/)
- [WordPress HTTPS - A Simple Tutorial](http://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/)

Comment: Problem was in the VHost config. Changed `AllowOverride` from `None` to `All` in two spots and viola. This makes it so your .htaccess files will be read. `None` will ignore your .htaccess files.